# Launch PowerApps from shortcut or command line

Tags: powerapps

I have PowerApps installed as a desktop app (from the Windows Store).

How can I launch a specific PowerApp from a shortcut or command line and have it open the local PowerApps app?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know the app id for the app you want to launch. You can find it in the URL when you visit your PowerApps app in a browser. The app id is between the last slash (/) and first question mark (?). E.g. `https://apps.powerapps.com/play/{your-app-id}?tenantID=...`

### Command line or batch file

```
explorer.exe "ms-apps:///providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apps/{your-app-id}"
```

### Shortcut on desktop or in a folder

File location: `"ms-apps:///providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apps/{your-app-id}"`

### Start menu tile

1. From your start menu choose **PowerApps**.
2. To the right of your app, choose the three dots > **Pin to Home**